# What are common Java vulnerabilities?

Tags: java, security

What are common Java vulnerabilities that can be exploited to gain some sort of access to a system? I have been thinking about it recently, and havent been able to come up with much of anything - integer overflow - maybe? race condition - what does it give you?

I am not looking for things like "sql injection in a web app".  I am looking for a relationship similar to buffer overflow - c/c++.

Any security experts out there that can help out? Thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why have you classified buffer overflow as a c/c++ vulnerability? It is possible even in Java, if the VM has the same vulnerability.

Comment: Usually, the vulnerabilities are in the application and not in the language itself.

Comment: @Vineet: To be fair, the risk of creating a buffer overflow in the *Java* code you write is non-existant; same for C# and other managed languages.  The risk of a buffer overflow in the VM itself is very low which eliminates some 99.9% of the risk overall.

Comment: I specified BOs as c/c++ vulnerability because they are not possible to be exploited in the Java language itself - it would be the underlying VM/core that would be exploited. That core is not written in Java.  I am looking for vulnerabilities in the interpreted language, that are common to all java applications, similar to the relationship when you used a strcp function without sanity check to a defined buffer in a c application.  i guess i wasnt defining buffer overflow as a c/c++ vulnerability, but more of that relationship between programming language to vuln.

Comment: @wuntee, what type of system are we talking about? A java web application, an application where the source runs on the client machine, etc? This will help answer your question more specifically.

Comment: It is more of a generic question - what vulnerabilities exist in the java interpreted language...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading most of the responses I think your question has been answered in an indirect way.  I just wanted to point this out directly.  Java doesn't suffer from the same problems you see in C/C++ because it protects the developer from these types of memory attacks (buffer overflow, heap overflow, etc).  Those things can't happen.  Because there is this fundamental protection in the language security vulnerabilities have moved up the stack.

They're now occurring at a higher level.  SQL injection, XSS, DOS, etc.  You could figure out a way to get Java to remotely load malicious code, but to do that would mean you'd need to exploit some other vulnerability at the services layer to remotely push code into a directory then trigger Java to load through a classloader.  Remote attacks are theoretically possible, but with Java it's more complicated to exploit.  And often if you can exploit some other vulnerability then why not just go after and cut java out of the loop.  World writable directories where java code is loaded from could be used against you.  But at this point is it really Java that's the problem or your sys admin or the vendor of some other service that is exploitable?

The only vulnerabilities that pose remote code potential I've seen in Java over the years have been from native code the VM loads.  The libzip vulnerability, the gif file parsing, etc.  And that's only been a handful of problems.  Maybe one every 2-3 years.  And again the vuln is native code loaded by the JVM not in Java code.

As a language Java is very secure.  Even these issues I discussed that can be theoretically attacked have hooks in the platform to prevent them.  Signing code thwarts most of this.  However, very few Java programs run with a Security Manager installed.  Mainly because of performance, usability, but mainly because these vulns are very limited in scope at best.  Remote code loading in Java hasn't risen to epidemic levels that buffer overflows did in the late 90s/2000s for C/C++.

Java isn't bullet proof as a platform, but it's harder to exploit than the other fruit on the tree.  And hackers are opportunistic and go for that low hanging fruit.

Comment: nice summary - one thing id like to note from an attackers perspective is that java can be used as an attack surface. since it is an interpreted language, you can write universal shells... i hadnt really thought about that until i read an article about it.

Answer (score 5):

Malicious Code injection.

Because Java (or any language using an interpreter at runtime), performs linkage at runtime, it is possible to replace the expected JARs (the equivalent of DLLs and SOs) with malicious ones at runtime.

This is a vulnerability, which is combated since the first release of Java, using various mechanisms.

- There are protections in places in the classloaders to ensure that java.* classes cannot be loaded from outside rt.jar (the runtime jar).
- Additionally, security policies can be put in place to ensure that classes loaded from different sources are restricted to performing only a certain set of actions - the most obvious example is that of applets. Applets are constrained by the Java security policy model from reading or writing the file system etc; signed applets can request for certain permissions.
- JARs can also be signed, and these signatures can be verified at runtime when they're loaded.
- Packages can also be sealed to ensure that they come from the same codesource. This prevents an attacker from placing classes into your package, but capable of performing 'malicious' operations.

If you want to know why all of this is important, imagine a JDBC driver injected into the classpath that is capable of transmitting all SQL statements and their results to a remote third party. Well, I assume you get the picture now.

Comment: This exact concept just came to mind, and I was going to mention it.  But, I have a hard time of wrapping my head around how one would take advantage of this... Can you provide a use case of how someone could inject a malicious jar?  A lot of overflow exploits are done simply by viewing a web page, or processing an image.  Maybe I am just thinking about it all wrong, and this is a whole different world of vulnerabilities...

Comment: Well, the last few sentences cover that. Since Java is usually used on the enterprise side of the industry, in the server farms, you would usually need a willing system administrator, or a compromised server to pull this off. I'll consider the second scenario since it is more plausible. Imagine a server (facing the internet) with a root access exploit or similar that allows an attacker to modify files on it at any possible location. Such an attacker would be able to upload his malicious payload present in, say the javax.sql.* namespace (contd.).....

Comment: If he were able to replace PreparedStatement.class with his own variety, and get it loaded before the one in rt.jar, then it is really left to his imagination on what is possible if such a security hole exists. He could record all the data flowing back and forth the application server and the database, and possibly upload it periodically to an external server. Thankfully, the protections in place are probably good enough for today.

Comment: To get more imaginative on this topic, assume that the Swing classes have been compromised by an attacker on the client desktop, and that all password fields now capture the plaintext password and uploads it to another site. It is similar to the Mozilla "sniffer" malware that was yanked off the addons list, a few days back.

Some of these attacks were possible before Sun introduced protection for the java.* and javax.* classes via the bootstrap classloader mechanism. Attacks would have been carried out using a custom classloader that loaded the attacker's classes before the classes from rt.jar

Comment: For example RMI downloads the code for stub classes from the remote system. The stub class can be something evil.

Comment: @wuntee As an example of injecting a malicious jar, consider the recent vulnerability in the Spring framework: http://www.springsource.com/security/cve-2010-1622

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a security expert, but there are some modules in our company that we can't code in java because it is so easy to de-compile java bytecode. We looked at obfuscation but if you want real obfuscation it comes only with a lot of problems (performance hit/loss of debug information).
One could steal our logics, replace the module with a modified version that will return incorrect results etc...

So compared to C/C++, I guess this is one "vulnerability" that stands out.

We also have a software license mechanism built-in in our java modules, but this can also be easily hacked by de-compiling and modifying the code.

Comment: People have been hacking and switching off software license mechanisms in C/C++ code for 30+ years.  Is it easier in Java?  Sure, but C/C++ isn't immune to these types of issues.  If people really want your software they'll get it.  I'd rather write my logic in a language like Java and make my job easier where I can move faster and create more value for my end customer than have the spectre of IP dictate my language choice.  Remember almost everything under the sun is not new.

Answer (score 1):

Including third party class files and calling upon them basically means you are running unsecure code.  That code can do anything it wants if you don't have security turned on.

Comment: The same is true of installing third party C or C++ libraries, and calling upon them. That code can do *more* anything than the Java code.